# Why in Google products like Docs or Talk, my username listed instead of the full name?

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-account-profile

For example in Google Docs others see me like this:

[image]

Same in Gmail Chat, my friends see my username in the list, instead of my name.

I've checked my account settings, and the profile, all seems to be configured well.

Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Your friends must have your name saved in their GMail Contacts along with your e-mail address, if they wish to see your name instead of your email id.

The name that you set for yourself will be visible to your friends on Google+, Orkut, Google Wave, Google Buzz (the social networking services from Google) and not any of the other Google Services at all.